# Inspect expression output of SQLAlchemy hybrid_properties

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following `@hybird_property` and `expression` defined in a SQLAlchemy model:

```py
class Widget(db.Model):
    # ...

    @hybrid_property
    def age(self):
        return (dt.datetime.utcnow() - self.date_created).seconds

    @age.expression
    def age(cls):
        return (
            func.strftime("%s", "now") - 
            func.strftime("%s", cls.date_created).cast(db.Integer)
        )
```

I'm looking for a convenient way to evaluate the output of the SQL `expression`. Right now, I either query against it and make sure it surfaces the expected rows or grep the query logs, but I'm hoping there's a way to evaluate both the `expression` and `property` versions from the Python Repl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see the SQL that will be rendered by the hybrid property, you can simply inspect `str(Widget.age.expression)`.

If you want to see actual values returned by this SQL, you can query for it directly, e.g. `session.query(Widget.age).filter(Widget.id == 1).one()`.

And of couse, to evaluate the `property` version, just get yourself a `Widget` instance and then inspect `widget.age`.

If you want to compare the results of the Python and SQL methods side by side, you could do something like this:

```py
>>> pairs = session.query(Widget, Widget.age).limit(10).all()
>>> [(widget.age, age) for widget, age in pairs]
```